# SQL query with multiple OR condition inside AND returns null or empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm trying to get those members who are going to match my filter criteria, but I am passing multiple OR condition inside the round brackets, and every condition which is inside the round brackets is, AND with another round bracket; however, the query does not work, and it returns an empty table, but whensoever I run the query with INTERSECT statement it returns the members. Still, it has been taking 3 seconds on 1 million records, and it is a very cost-paying operation on the server-side, and it will increase if the records increase. Could someone help me why my first query is not working or if I use the second query, is there any way to attenuate the time?

My actual table
[image]

***First Query, which returns Empty table***

```
SELECT custom_attribute_values.attributable_id as Member_id FROM custom_attribute_values
WHERE (("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" = 'Female') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" = 'Male'))
AND (("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Widowed') OR
("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Divorced') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Never married') OR
("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Married') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Separated'))
```

[image]

***Second Query, which returns the result in, which I am interested but taking too much time***

```
SELECT custom_attribute_values.attributable_id FROM custom_attribute_values
WHERE (("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" = 'Female') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" = 'Male'))
INTERSECT
SELECT custom_attribute_values.attributable_id FROM custom_attribute_values WHERE (("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Widowed') OR
("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Divorced') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Never married') OR
("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Married') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Separated'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have conflicting conditions on each row.  I'm pretty sure you want aggregation:

```
SELECT cav.attributable_id as Member_id
FROM custom_attribute_values cav
WHERE ("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" IN ('Female', 'Male')) OR 
      ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" IN ('Widowed', 'Divorced', 'Never married', 'Married', 'Separated')
      )
GROUP BY cav.attributable_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "custom_attribute_id") = 2;  -- both match
```

The `WHERE` checks that either condition match.  The `HAVING` validates that both match for a given member.

Note that you should avoid double quotes for identifiers.  They just make queries harder to write and to read.

Comment: thank you but I would like to run query on AND instead of OR
WHERE ("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" IN ('Female', 'Male')) AND 
      ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" IN ('Widowed', 'Divorced', 'Never married', 'Married', 'Separated')
      )

like this please could you help me how it is possible  thank you

Comment: @Adnan . . . You are missing the point.  The `HAVING` clause takes core of being sure that both conditions are matched on a member id.

Comment: You mean that the *HAVING* Clause has to satisfy both conditions either I use OR in the *WHERE* Clause?
right

Comment: @Adnan . . . The `WHERE` clause filters all possible rows down to the ones that many *any* of the conditions.  The `HAVING` chooses member ids that have *both* conditions valid for the member -- albeit in different rows.